# Android studio unexpected element <uses-permisson> found in <manifest><application>. ERROR

Tags: android-studio-3.0

**I'm having this problem when I try to create an APK
help me guys thanks.
....
....
....

here Manifest.xml
**

```js
<uses-permisson android:name="android.permisson.SEND_SMS"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="ilkuygulama">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".startingPage"
        android:label="ilkuygulama">

    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: You need to show what you have tried, your code at least and remember to see through your question before posting it, as you have not included the need code or error message for us to help you.

Comment: Do not add images of code. Copy-paste it into the question instead